# vuejs keeps rebinding unnecessarily

Tags: vue.js, data-binding

I am having this strange issue. I make this most basic vuejs component's template. And the definedInVueData is defined in the component's data.

I have this notInComponentData.fakeThing to break the binding intentionally, so, every time it binds and failed, the error is printed on the console.

Every time I change the value of definedInComponentData, it updates the first div, which is fine,
but, it also try to rebind the notInComponentData.fakeThing again. The div is unrelated to definedInVueData, thus, it shouldn't have been updated.

Now, imagine notInComponentData.fakeThing is actually data in the component, it is used to generate a really complex div structure (paging does not apply, we need entire data to be rendered). It keeps trying to re-bind this large data when the data is not changed. We are taking a major performance hit because we have animation in another component. But, this component slows down the entire page.

Is there a way to tell veujs not to keep rebinding something where the source is not changed?

Thank you

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-container
      fluid
    >
      <div>
        aaaa {{ definedInComponentData }}
      </div>
      <div>
        bbb {{ notInComponentData.fakeThing }}
      </div>
    </v-container>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Comment: If you do not want an element be rendered, you should use v-if. So the element will not be rendered in your html.

Comment: @Danizavtz, can you elaborate on that? If I set v-if to always be true, this will stop the re-binding on data that's not changed? I tried v-if and that still triggers the rebinding. I wanted to reuse the previously generated html instead of rebinding it again.

Comment: If say you want to render a button login if user does not have access token. Else you want to show a edit profile if user has access token, you could use the v-if to check for access token with v-if, but only button to <kbd>login</kbd> or button to <kbd>edit profile</kbd> will be rendered in html. But not both.

Comment: @Danizavtz I wanted to show the button always. I just don't want to keep regenerating the same button every time something else around the button changes.

Comment: Sorry can't help, i was not sure if it was what you wanted.